# Use of memset to prevent ''variable-sized object may not be initialized'

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I am trying to set values to a 2D array (envisage a game board or a some grid) using the code below but I receive 'variable-sized object may not be initialized' error.

I tried solving it using memset but to no avail.

Many thanks and some hints would be much appreciated.

---

```
// constants
#define DIM_MIN 3
#define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];


void init(void)
{
  int highest = d^2;

  for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            int board[i][j] = highest - 1;
        }
    }
    if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        int board[d-1][d-2] = 2;
        int board[d-1][d-3] = 1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You tell us about `memset` but then don't bother showing us how you use it?

Comment: Strangely, you put `int` in front of every use of the previously declared `board`, but `d` is still unknown.

Comment: Also `d^2` isn't the way to square `d`.  Try `d*d` instead.

Comment: @BoPersson Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the code in `for` loop body, which says

```
  int board[i][j] = highest - 1;
```

what you want probably is

```
  board[i][j] = highest - 1;
```

The same goes for the `if` condition body, too.

To elaborate regarding the error message, `int board[i][j] = highest - 1;` tries to define a new [VLA (variable length array)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which cannot be initialized.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization* (*emphasis mine*)

> **The type of the entity to be initialized** shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
>   object type that is **not a variable length array type.**

Comment: Dear Sourav, many thanks for this. I understand now, thank you for the source too.